# Rails redirect all nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way that I can redirect all the child routes to `root_url` or to some other routes depending on the type of authorization? Here are my `routes`

```rb
resources :invitations, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

namespace :app do
  resources :projects, only: [:index, :show, :create] do
    resources :changelogs, only: [:index]
    resources :team_members, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

The `app` namespaced routes, that is the routes starting with `/app/projects/:id` should be redirect to either `root_url` or to `invitations_url` depending on the type of authorization.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `devise` and have a `user` table with a column `admin:boolean`, you can check for admin in `routes.rb` like this:

```
  authenticated :user, lambda {|u| u.admin? } do
    namespace :app do
      #your routes
    end
  end
```

This would make "your nested routes" completely unavailable for unauthenticated user and users that are not admin.

If you want redirects, you can add something like this in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/stories', to: redirect('/articles')
```

**Otherwise** you can simply do redirects in the controllers like `projects_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:show, :edit]

def authenticate_admin
  unless current_user.admin? redirect_to root_path, alert: "You are not authorized"
end
```